# I got a Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while trying to run Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was trying to run Xcode and everything went pretty well. But when i tried to do some common by pressing the button, it redirected me back to the View Controller and it was written "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

[image: Image of the codes]

Comment: Button not connected?

Comment: Yeah check your connections.

Comment: Check your outlet connection for this button in xcode view controller & this file.

Answer (score 2):

you should probably check to make sure your button outlet is connected properly. Go to the storyboard and ctrl click on your button and check to make sure there's an outlet connection.